# Change Artifactory LDAP Server via Config File Not Working

Tags: artifactory

Currently Artifactory 6.19.1 on premise on RHEL 7.7 via yum repository. I was about to do an upgrade but wanted to make sure things were working correctly when I noticed I could not login.

The LDAP server that I had configured in my Artifactory was shut down (I was not informed ahead of time that this was going to happen) and I cannot log into my instance any more and therefore cannot change the LDAP server via the web interface. I have tried creating a artifactory.config.xml based on the artifactory.config.bootstrap.xml and artifactory.config.latest.xml that seem to be generated when it restarts.

Unfortunately, despite changing the host in the configuration files, when artifactory restarts it still tries to use the old LDAP server. I have seen this in the logs:

```
2021-06-10 07:49:38,820 [http-nio-8081-exec-5] [WARN ] (o.a.s.l.ArtifactoryLdapAuthenticationProvider:198) - Failed to authenticate user 'USERNAME' via LDAP: communication error
```

I have packet captured the host during this time and can see it trying to use the old LDAP server. I have restarted the Artifactory service numerous times with no change and tried over different days (so 30 minute cache should not be an issue). The regenerated configuration files such as artifactory.config.latest.xml show the change, but something appears to be cached or not updating or something.

I have tried setting a user in security/access/bootstrap.creds and that does not work either, it tries to use LDAP to authenticate that user.

Looking for a way to force either local authentication via bootstrap creds or to force Artifactory to actually use the configuration I set by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by using a firewalld command to redirect the IP:

firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 nat OUTPUT 0 -d ORIGINAL_HOST 6 -p tcp --dport 389 -j DNAT --to-destination NEW_HOST:389

After that I could log into the web and change things normally.

<sub>*Added on behalf of the question author.*</sub>